# MemSQL after truncate table reset id to 1

Tags: singlestore

I am using MemSQL.
I want to reset Auto increment id to 1 after I issue a truncate table command. I issued the following commands:-

```
truncate table BOOKS;
AGGREGATOR SYNC AUTO_INCREMENT ON db.BOOKS;
```

But when I insert rows after that the id continues to increase as per earlier insertions.

How can I reset id to 1 in MemSQL?

Answer (score 1):

MemSQL doesn't support ALTER TABLE  AUTO_INCREMENT= to reset the auto_increment value yet.  The only way to reset it is to drop and recreate the table right now.

Keep in mind that auto_increments behave differently in MemSQL compared to other databases. For example, the auto_increment values of rows inserted one after another on different aggregators won't be consecutive.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we don't support that as of 4.1.
You can always drop and recreate the table thought :P.

Comment: the year is 2021, im using singlestore and this is still not supported. any plans to develop this?